# javascript check if function parameter meets a condition

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a basic "quest" function and have run into a few issues.
[This is what I've done so far](http://jsfiddle.net/ozn7n64c/1/)

### **JS**

```
var clicks = 0;
var coins = 10;

var Quests = function(type, required, reward, message) {
    this.type = type;
    this.required = required;
    this.reward = reward;
    this.message = message;
    this.quest = function() {
        if (this.type >= this.required) {
            coins += this.reward;
            return this.message;
        } else {
            alert('You don\'t have enough ' + required);
        }
    };
};
quest1 = new Quests(clicks, 10, 50, 'You completed this quest!');
quest2 = new Quests(clicks, 5, 50, 'You completed this quest!');

theQuests = [quest1, quest2];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#click').click(function() {
        clicks += 1;
        $('#queststuff').text(clicks);
    });
    $('#quest').click(function() {
        $('#queststuff').html(Quests[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)].quest());
    });
});
```

### **HTML**

```
   <button id="quest">quest</button>
   <button id="click">click me!</button>
   <div id="queststuff">   
   </div>
```

Eventually I'll be using something other than clicks, but for now I wanted to just get the basic function working. I'm fairly new to functions, but at the moment when clicking 'quest' nothing happens, while I'm wanting the `alert` to display. I've obviously gone wrong *somewhere* in my code. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning `clicks`, an immutable `Number`, to `this.type`. Its value is 0 initially, and `this.type` thus stays 0 after the assignment. You should compare `clicks` to `this.required` within the `quest` method.

Here's a [**jsFiddle fork**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/j5gcuwgt/) version using `data-attributes`

Comment: Thanks! I was fiddling around and figured out that using `clicks` works (was editing it into my question as you posted) but eventually I would like to use different things (Like needing a certain amount of strength or magic) which is why I was trying with `this.type`. Is there a way I can force `this.type` to update on click, so I can use different variables as the required type?

Comment: Nope, it would require another setup. You could try working with a `data-attribute` on the button. See this fork of the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/j5gcuwgt/

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues.

- When you create a new object `quest1` with `new Objects` you pass `clicks` into it. At the time you pass `clicks` it equals to `0`. And inside that object method `quest1.quest()`, you check if clicks (`this.type`) is greater/equal to required clicks (`this.required`). `this.type` equals to `0`. It will never return true. Since you're creating multiple quests, clicks should be specific to these quests (objects). It shouldn't be global.
- Another one is in this line:

  `$('#queststuff').html(Quests[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)].quest());`

  I believe you wanted to address to your `theQuests` array. `Quests[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)].quest()` simply won't work. Even if you change your code to `theQuests[0].quest()` or `quest1.quest()` it still won't work. See above, and since there are multiple quests, first you need to check which one is active.

You should review your code. Here's something to get you started. Of course, it needs further improvement and styling. [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ozn7n64c/5/)

```
var Quest = function (requiredClicks, reward, message) {
    this.clicks = 0;
    this.coins = 0;
    this.requiredClicks = requiredClicks;
    this.reward = reward;
    this.message = message;
    this.check = function () {
        if (this.clicks >= this.requiredClicks) {
            this.coins += this.reward;
            return this.message;
        } else {
            alert('You don\'t have enough clicks: ' + this.clicks + "/" + this.requiredClicks);
        }
    };
    this.click = function() {
        this.clicks++;
    };
};
var quest1 = new Quest(10, 50, 'You completed this quest!');

$('#click').click(function () {
    quest1.click();
    $('#queststuff').text(quest1.clicks);
});
$('#quest').click(function () {
    $('#queststuff').html(quest1.check());
});
```